# Миграция на PHP8

Tags: php, миграция, php5, php8

Первоначальный код полностью выложил здесь:

[PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/iRu2Uf4x)

У меня появилась ошибка:

> Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces
> is no longer supported in **** on line 550

В строке:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) $res .= ord($text{$i}) . "-";
```

Я вроде как исправил на:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) $res .= ord($text[$i]) . "-";
```

Но появилась другая ошибка:

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in *** on
> line 76

На строке:

```
$real = $row['sip'];
```

Не подскажите - как это можно поправить?

P.S. Ранее не часто работал с PHP, поэтому не пинайте сильно)

Comment: Ну если появилась такая ошибка, значит `$row` — не массив, а bool. А вот почему и где он стал bool — это вам лучше знать в вашем коде

Comment: А при попытке читать из базы случайно не false возвращается при ошибке?

Comment: Как вообще начало вопроса связано с его концом? Даже ни одной общей переменной не вижу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написано прямо (если кинуть текст в переводчик):

`$row` - у вас булева. Поэтому работать с ней как с массивом не представляется возможным

Answer (score 0):

$row - скорее всего False а не массив со строчкой.

`var_dump ($row)` в помощь.